# I keep receiving a compile error in excel with my macro

Tags: vba, excel

I keep receiving a compile error in excel with my macro.

I'm trying to make a macro in a shared workbook (I will unshare the workbook to use the macro) and have it copy over to another file (The master file that is unshared and has graphs)

```
Sub Macro()

Dim directory As String, FILEnAME As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop"
FILEnAME = Dir(directory & "Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database")

Do While FILEnAME <> ""

Loop

Workbooks.Open (directory & FILEnAME)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(FILEnAME).Worksheets
total = Workbooks("Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls").Worksheets.Count
Workbooks(FILEnAME).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy_
after: Workbooks("Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls").Worksheets (total)
Next sheet

Workbooks(FILEnAME).Close

FILEnAME = Dir()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

**Recently updated code still getting a compile error**

```
Sub Macro()

Dim directory As String, FILEnAME As String, sht As Worksht, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\"
FILEnAME = Dir(directory & "Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls")

Do While FILEnAME <> ""

Loop

Workbooks.Open (directory & FILEnAME)

For Each sht In Workbooks(FILEnAME).Workshts
total = Workbooks("Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls").Workshts.Count
Workbooks(FILEnAME).Workshts(sht.Name).Copy_
after: Workbooks("Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls").Worksht (total)
Next sht

Workbooks(FILEnAME).Close

FILEnAME = Dir()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you receive the error?

Comment: in the `after:` there should be `Worksheet(total)` probably and not Worksheets

Comment: The "Sub Macro ()" is highlighted in yellow and the Worksheets is highlighted in the after as you noted.

Comment: I tried deleting the (s) in "Worksheets" to make it Worksheet(total). Now I'm getting a Run-time error '1004' Excel cannot access 'Desktop'. The document may be read-only or                                                encrypted. Neither of which are true.

Comment: There are at least a few issues here. 1. `Sheet` is a reserved word. Use `sht` instead. 2. There is no backslash at the end of the your directory. 3. There is no extension on your file name.

Comment: Dave how would I fix this ?

Comment: You need `After:=` (you forgot the `=`.

Comment: You also should not change `Worksht`, that **does** need to be `Worksheets`, since that is the collection name.

Comment: I added the = sign and still getting an error my code line turns red.

Comment: @tbur `Sheet` is not a reserved keyword. The initial loop is valid. The only downside of using this name is that you cannot access the global `Sheet` object inside the function

Comment: Dave I apologize as I'm horrible at coding. I'm getting confused quickly. I really would like to make this work.

Comment: @JoshuaBuckley why don't you look at my answer? The code below does compile. Whether it raises other errors at run-time, I did not test that. But it will compile, and that I am certain of.

Comment: @ Dave   back to the run-time errors it's pointing to the "Workbooks.Open (directory & FILENAME) portion of the code. I did just see your answer below too, I'm relatively new to this site and you're the only one that seems to be consistently commenting back.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles.

Note that the named arguments like `After` in the `Copy` method must be stated like `After:=...`, you had forgotten the `=`.

I also note in your revised code that you have changed `.Worksheets` to `.Workshts`. I am not sure why you did this, but there is no such member as a `Worksht` so that will also raise an error.

You need to make sure that your `FILENAME` variable has a file extension. Yours did not.

FYI from the Debug menu you can test compile the project at any time, and it should help identify what the source of the error is.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim directory As String, FILENAME As String, sht As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\"
FILENAME = Dir(directory & "Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls")

Do While FILENAME <> ""

Loop

Workbooks.Open (directory & FILENAME)

For Each sht In Workbooks(FILENAME).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls").Worksheets.Count

    Workbooks(FILENAME).Worksheets(sht.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks("Copy of AMS Engineering Transitions Database.xls").Worksheets(total)

Next sht

Workbooks(FILENAME).Close

FILENAME = Dir()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Note that this loop does **nothing**:

```
Do While FILENAME <> ""

Loop
```